# How to replace all characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string that is passed by parameter and I have to replace all occurrences of it in another string, ex:

```
function r(text, oldChar, newChar)
{
    return text.replace(oldChar, newChar); // , "g")
}
```

The characters passed could be **any** character, including `^`, `|`, `$`, `[`, `]`, `(`, `)`...

Is there a method to replace, for example, all `^` from the string `I ^like^ potatoes` with `$`?

Comment: Doesn't your function already do that?

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt No, JavaScript's `String.prototype.replace` only replaces the first occurrence of strings; you need to use a regular expression with the `g`lobal flag if you want global replacement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function r(t, o, n) {
    return t.split(o).join(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply pass '^' to the JavaScript replace function it should be treated as a string and not as a regular expression. However, using this method, it will only replace the first character. A simple solution would be:

```
function r(text, oldChar, newChar)
{
    var replacedText = text;

    while(text.indexOf(oldChar) > -1)
    {
        replacedText = replacedText.replace(oldChar, newChar);
    }

    return replacedText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a RegExp object instead of a simple string:

```
text.replace(new RegExp(oldChar, 'g'), newChar);
```

Comment: Fails for: `var text = "^xxx^"; text.replace(new RegExp("^", 'g'), "$");`

Comment: Note that you'll need to escape the character in case it's a special regex char, e.g. "\", ".", "(", etc. Thus `new RegExp("\\"+oldChar,"g")`

Comment: @Phrogz that requires a list of all possible escaping sequences as I don't know what is coming on the parameter

Comment: You would have to escape the `^` with two backslashes to make it work: `var text = "^xxx^"; text.replace(new RegExp("\\^", 'g'), "$");`

Comment: @BrunoLM You are right; while JS will allow `/\z/` and treat it the same as `/z/`, there are a few broken cases such as `/\x/` being treated as an empty hexadecimal character instead of just an `/x/`.